# Javascript get element ID stack outputs in one text area

Tags: javascript, textarea

How can i click both buttons and get in one text area both results one after the other? ATM the one button erases the output of the other button.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="removeTone()">Remove Tone</button> 
    <button onclick="greeklish()">Greeklish</button> 

    <textarea id="main_textarea"> </textarea>
    <textarea id="main_textarea2"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
function removeTone () {
    var str = document.getElementById("main_textarea").value;
    var res = str.replace(/ά/gi, "α");
    res = res.replace(/ά/gi, "α");
    document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value = res;
}
function greeklish (){
    var str = document.getElementById("main_textarea").value;
    var res = str.replace(/α/gi, "a");
    res = res.replace(/ά/gi, "a");
    document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value = res;
}
```

Comment: You mean to say that you want to "append" the result instead of defining the value?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeTone () {
    var str = document.getElementById("main_textarea").value;
    var res = str.replace(/ά/gi, "α");
    res = res.replace(/ά/gi, "α");
  var str2 = document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value;
    document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value = str2 + ((str2 !== '')?'\r':'') + res;
}
function greeklish (){
    var str = document.getElementById("main_textarea").value;
    var res = str.replace(/α/gi, "a");
    res = res.replace(/ά/gi, "a");
  var str2 = document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value;
    document.getElementById("main_textarea2").value = str2 + ((str2 !== '')?'\r':'') + res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="removeTone()">Remove Tone</button> 
    <button onclick="greeklish()">Greeklish</button> 

    <textarea id="main_textarea"> </textarea>
    <textarea id="main_textarea2"></textarea>
```

Is that you want ?

Comment: Thank toy very much! Yes that's it but i just needed it one line lower. Is that possible?